# modify floyd's-warshall algorithm so it always adds source path to pairs

Tags: algorithm, graph

If I want to find the minimum paths of a pair's path how could it be? For example having 3 nodes and distance between 1-2 is min{d1+d2, d1+d12, d2+d12} as in the picture, could I find it from Floyd's algorithm? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoaM6.jpg)

Comment: The provided graph in the picture is a directed graph and according to the picture there is only one path that is a valid path between 1 and 2 and it is d12. If it was an undirected graph, then the case would have been different.

Comment: @zenwraight In my problem the source is a water reservoir so I am searching the construction I'll make to see if it will cost me less to get water on city 1 and city 2 through getting it by from the reservoir to town 1 + town 2 or by town 1 getting the water and then passing it to town 2 via path 12 etc.